# Detected a new line within a series of numbers in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Let's say I have a series of numbers like...

```
 1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
 9 0
```

How could I step through each int, but stop when I reach a new line? I'm currently using `nextInt()` and I know that `nextLine()` will detect the new line, but I'm not sure how to piece that together. Is it best to take the entire line, and parse the string into separate ints? Or is there a more fluid method of doing this?

For my example, I would want the program to store `1 2 3 4`, `5 6 7 8`, `9 0` all in their own separate array.

For more clarification, I'm using the `java.util.Scanner` and I'm reading a text file.

Comment: "More fluid" will depend on what you ultimately intend to do with the data and how much data there is.  Add some more detail on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean you want '1 2 3 4' in one array, '5 6 7 8' in other array and so on?

Comment: @mahendraliya: Yes, exactly. That's what I meant :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Scanner`, read the entire line into a String, and then construct a Scanner on the String.

Comment: That is a fantastic idea. I would have never thought of that! So simple too!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the text file in read mode and read the entire line with `readLine()` method.

Then you can split the line read with the space ( ' ' ) character which will automatically give you an array.

You can do this till the end of file.

```
import java.io.*;
class FileRead 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
      try{
    // Open the file 
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    delimiter = " ";
    int myArr[];
    //Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      myArr = strLine.split(delimiter);
      // store this array into some global array or process it in the way you want.
    }
    //Close the input stream
    in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.